# how to get child elements of a groupbox in silverlight?

Tags: silverlight-4.0, telerik, silverlight-toolkit, groupbox

I have a telerik groupbox for silverlight.

i have a user control in which i had a groupbox (x:Name="grpBox") with three controls (ctrl1, ctrl2,ctrl3).

I have dragged and dropped the usercontrol in page.xaml and named it as "UCl1".

so now in code behind of the page.xaml i want to get/set dependancy properties of ctrl1/ctrl2/ctrl3.

I also have another User control with TextBox, TextBlock and custom dependancy property LabelText.

How can i do that?

Code:

User control content:

```
  <telerik:GroupBox Header="Header" x:Name="grpBox">
        <StackPanel>
            <TextBlock x:Name="ctrl1"/>
            <TextBlock x:Name="ctrl2"/>
            <TextBox x:Name="ctrl3"/>
            <my:myUserContro2 x:Name="LabeledTextBox" LabelText="FirstName:" />
        </StackPanel>
    </telerik:GroupBox>
```

Page.XAml:

```
 <my1:uc1 x:Name="UCl1" />
```

now in codebehiind page.xaml.cs:

UCl1.grpBox.ctrl1.text="Welcome...!";
Also i want to set custom dependancy property value as follows:

UCl1.grpBox.LabeledTextBox.LabelText="Name:";

I tried, but after UCl1.grpBox i am not able to access ctrl1/2/3.

Any help greatly appreciated.
Thanks.

Comment: Can't you access those controls directly?

Answer (score 0):

The names are private you need to expose them via public properties. Unless you actually want to bind to the properties our animate them in some way a standard clr property should suffice